# How to trigger Actionbar menu items in android app

Tags: android

I have webview in my app, which loads some url's. In this webview, I am seeing Actionbar menu (Cut, Copy, Paste, SelectAll, Settings) on top of the app, while long pressing on the texts in the loaded webpages.

I am trying to make an alert for this menus, while click on them. If user touch's `cut` I need to show an alert of `You clicked Copy, Are you sure to Copy this?`.

For this, I am overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` method, but not sure that this is right way. There is no `onActionBarItemSelected` method.

My mainActivity extends `ActionBarActivity`

Here my code, I used for this triggering,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d("MenuItem  clicked - inside onOptionsItemSelected");
    if (item.getItemId() == R.attr.actionModeCopyDrawable) {
        Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "Copy");
        ShowAlert("You clicked Copy, Are you sure to Copy this?");
    }
    return true;
}

public void ShowAlert(String str) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder1.setMessage(str);
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

But there is no alert and not even a log message of `MenuItem  clicked - inside onOptionsItemSelected`, while click on the Copy menu.

What I am missing here, hope someone can assist here.

Comment: you should use **R.id.someId** instead of **R.attr.actionModeCopyDrawable**

Comment: This is what the Id for that Copy menu in R.java

Comment: pls read this article [handling events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu)

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for your support indeed. In fact the log message inside the onOptionsItemSelected method doesn't show any logs before checking the menu id. I updated my question, pls take a look.

Comment: does activity have **onCreateOptionsMenu**?

Comment: Yes, it has that method also override.  `@Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
 }`

Comment: read [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml). It should clarify all.